# The XSD tool skips a nested level

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I hope I am correctly phrasing my problem. When we run the xsd tool on our xsd to create classes, the code is not exactly representing the xsd on one section. It is like this:

XSD: 'BaliseGroups' => Collection of 'BaliseGroup' => Collection of 'Balise'

Code: 'BaliseGroups' => Collection of type 'Balise' named 'BaliseGroup'...

```xml
<xs:element name="BaliseGroups">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Een verzameling balisegroepen</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BaliseGroup" type="tBaliseGroup"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="tBaliseGroup">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Een balisegroep, </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Balise" type="tBalise" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="8"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="tBalise">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Type voor een balise</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tTrackAsset"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Code

```cs
public partial class BaliseGroups
{
    private tBalise[] baliseGroupField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Balise", IsNullable = false)]
    public tBalise[] BaliseGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.baliseGroupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.baliseGroupField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the generated C# code block it creates a Property BaliseGroup of type Balise[]. This should be of type tBaliseGroup[].

I have a conjecture that there is something wrong with the xsd, but I cannot figure out what..

Comment: BaliseGroups is of type BaliseGroup. 
The content of complex type BaliseGroup is an array of Balise. 
So BaliseGroup *contains* an array of Balise, and nothing else. Seems reasonable to provide a method that returns an array of Balise from a BaliseGroups.

Comment: But it will not result in  'BaliseGroups' => Collection of 'BaliseGroup' => Collection of 'Balise' when you deserialize to XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. By annotating in the xsd that 'BaliseGroup' has a maxOccurs of 'unbounded' it creates the collection of 'BaliseGroup' in 'BaliseGroups'. Here is the change:

```xml
<xs:element name="BaliseGroups">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Een verzameling balisegroepen</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BaliseGroup" type="tBaliseGroup" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```